# iTunes rss feed - Podcast link broken on mobile and no notifications

Tags: xml, rss, app-store-connect, itunes, podcast

I have a RSS feed located at http://prettygoodsports.com/pod.rss

The feed produces the podcast which can be found at https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/pretty-good-sports-podcast/id1359888230

When accessing that link or any other link relating to my podcast on Mobile device, I am not taken to the correct podcast home page.  In addition,  when I refresh my feed via iTunes, I don't receive a notification for new episodes.

My current theory is that saving the file as a .rss extension could be causing the issue?  I have resaved to xml and resubmitted.  I will update if anything changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the file extension from .rss to .xml solved my issue.